# Missing tested up to on readme text validator

Tags: theme-development

My theme has almost 9 problems which I have to fix. One is readme text where the reviewer says it has to fix like license. And he provided me the url to check validator. Here https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers/readme-validator/

I fix the license ...but the online validator shows "Tested up to" is missing. Where I am sure it is added there.

```
Requires at least: 4.5
Tested up to: 5.3.2
Stable tag: 1.0.3
License: GNU General Public License v2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html
```

So how should I fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the developer docs here: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/#how-the-readme-is-parsed .

The example readme on that page explains all of what is required, what to put there, and the other optional items.

There are also several readme generators that might help you. One is here: https://tools.wedevs.com/readme/ . Others are available.